Errors when trying to run Virtual Device with API level 34 (Android 14)
I am setting up Android Studio (2024.1.1 Patch 1, Koala) on Windows 10 for some React Native development, but Android Studio comes with API 35 preinstalled, whereas React Native targets API 34. I am able to run virtual devices on API 35, but when I install the SDK for Android 14 and API 34 and set up a virtual device it does not work. I can run the virtual device but it stays in the background, and when I click on it in the taskbar it throws up 5 or so "Unable to execute" errors due to missing dlls.
Does anyone have experience with errors such as this, or know what my next troubleshooting steps are? I have tried different phones (virtual), I have tried removing API 35, I have tried both the Intel and the Google API system images for API 34.
When installing API level 34 I am installing, under the heading Android 14.0 ("UpsideDownCake") in SDK Platforms:
Android SDK Platform 34,
Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image,
Intel x86_64 Atom System Image,
And in SDK Tools:
34.0.0,
Android Emulator,
Android SDK Platform-Tools,
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) - Deprecated,
Path for SDK: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
The error messages I get suggest that I am missing the following .dlls:
libprotobuf.dll,
libglib2_windows_msvc-x86_64.dll,
libandroid-emu-metrics.dll,
libandroid-emu-agents.dll,
All these .dlls are present in sdk\emulator\lib64\
The virtual device does boot up, and I get the error messages when trying to open it. It does not crash however, I can keep trying to bring it up and get the error messages every time.
Thanks in advance

I have found the cause of the issue and the solution. First a few clarifications: The .dll errors were a red herring, they were caused by the right-clicking of the process name in the taskbar causing Windows to try to launch a new qemu process without launch parameters, and had nothing to do with this issue.
The other is that it was not an API 34 issue, but rather an issue with all other devices other than Pixel Fold. Only the Pixel Fold worked, regardless of API. All other devices did not work, again regardless of API.
So it turns out the issue was due to the scaling of my TV which I am using as a monitor being 300% due to its size. I managed to fix the issue by going to the C:\Users\User.android\avd\Pixel_4a_API_34.avd and opening the file emulator-user.ini. Here I changed the values to the following:
window.x = 0 window.y = 0 window.scale = 0.01
Changing the coordinates on their own did not fix any issues. It seems the issue was the scaling of the monitor being at 300% and then the window.scale setting together causing the window to fail to draw. After applying these settings the emulator launches just fine and sets new values that continue to work afterwards.

You can do one thing just tap on a icon of emulator present on task bar then press ctrl+shift+esc to open task manager then expand the window for qemu under that you will get android emulator option, right click on that and select maximize and you issue will be solved.

This does not work as the issue is with actually drawing the window, not it being out of bounds or not maximized. I have since making this post identified the issue with the help of the Android Studio issuetracker. I will post the cause and solution as an answer
